# c++ method visibility inheritance through different namespace in g++

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces, g++

a little question about method visibility in c++. say this code :

```
namespace A
{
   class AA
   {
      public :
         AA() {}

         void foo1(int a) {} //will be overloaded in B::BB
         void foo2(int a) {} //will be overloaded in B::BB
         void foo3(int a) {} //won't be overloaded
   };
}

using namespace A;

namespace B
{
   class BB : public A::AA // ( A:: facultative but it's to test without the using namespace )
   {
      public:
         BB() : AA() {}

         void foo1(int b, int d) { AA::foo1(b); } //works
         void bar3(int b, int d) { foo3(b); } //works

         void foo2(int b, int d) { foo2(b); }
         //doesn't work, "error : B::BB::foo2(int) not declared"
   };
}
```

It is something like... very weird for me : why does the compiler search foo2 in B::BB while it finds correctely foo3 ? I mean, I understand it's because I overloaded foo2 and not foo3 but why a such behavior ? is there something in the standard which talks about this case or is it a misbehaviour / bug in g++ ? (Note: I've the error on gnu90, gnu99 and c++11)

Comment: When you overload a member function which is defined in a base class, you also *hide* the other overloads from unqualified lookup. That's why you need the explicit namespace for `foo1` and `foo2`. I'd look it up in the standard if I had it handy.

Comment: Ah yes, indeed the namespace is not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apparent overloads in class BB are not, really: they *shadow* the member functions of same name from class AA.

It's the same idea as redefining a name in an inner scope: it shadows the same name in some outer scope, so that the outer scope isn't considered no matter how meaningful that would be.

You can either qualify calls, like

```
void foo2(int b, int d) { AA::foo2(b); }
```

or introduce the AA functions as visible overloads by

```
using AA::foo2;
```